# python changing integers/ floats to None in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

hey I'm trying to change elements in my Python list, and I just can't get it to work.

```
content2 = [-0.112272999846, -0.0172778364044, 0, 
            0.0987861891257, 0.143225416783, 0.0616318333661,
            0.99985834, 0.362754457762, 0.103690909138,
            0.0767353098528, 0.0605534405723, 0.0, 
            -0.105599793882, -0.0193182826135, 0.040838960163,]

 for i in range((content2)-1):
        if content2[i] == 0.0:
            content2[i] = None

print content2
```

It needs to produce:

```
   content2 = [-0.112272999846, -0.0172778364044, None,
               0.0987861891257, 0.143225416783, 0.0616318333661,
               0.99985834, 0.362754457762, 0.103690909138,
               0.0767353098528, 0.0605534405723, None,
               -0.105599793882, -0.0193182826135, 0.040838960163,]
```

I've tried various other methods too. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Try `len(content2) -1` as the argument to `range`.

Comment: @chepner that's still wrong. `range` is exclusive remember. So that would go up to `len(content2) - 2` using your code

Comment: I knew something about that looked funny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should avoid modifying by index in Python

```
>>> content2 = [-0.112272999846, -0.0172778364044, 0, 0.0987861891257,
 0.143225416783,     0.0616318333661, 0.99985834, 0.362754457762, 0.103690909138,
 0.0767353098528, 0.0605534405723, 0.0, -0.105599793882, -0.0193182826135, 
0.040838960163]
>>> [float(x) if x else None for x in content2]
[-0.112272999846, -0.0172778364044, None, 0.0987861891257, 0.143225416783, 0.0616318333661, 0.99985834, 0.362754457762, 0.103690909138, 0.0767353098528, 0.0605534405723, None, -0.105599793882, -0.0193182826135, 0.040838960163]
```

To mutate `content2` to the result of this list comprehension, do the following:

```
content2[:] = [float(x) if x else None for x in content2]
```

Your code didn't work because:

```
range((content2)-1)
```

you are trying to subtract `1` from a `list`. Also the `range` endpoint is **exclusive** (it goes up to the endpoint `- 1`, which you are subtracting `1` from again) so what you meant was `range(len(content2))`

This modification of your code works:

```
for i in range(len(content2)):
    if content2[i] == 0.0:
        content2[i] = None
```

It's nicer to use the implicit fact that `int`s in Python equal to `0` evaluate to false so this works equally fine as well:

```
for i in range(len(content2)):
    if not content2[i]:
        content2[i] = None
```

You can get used to doing that for lists and tuples as well instead of checking `if len(x) == 0` as recommended by [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id37)

The list comprehension I suggested:

```
content2[:] = [float(x) if x else None for x in content2]
```

Is semantically equivalent to

```
res = []
for x in content2:
    if x: # x is not empty (0.0)
        res.append(float(x))
    else:
        res.append(None)
content2[:] = res # replaces items in content2 with those from res
```

Comment: Please include an explanation on what you're doing. I doubt anyone new to Python understands what a list comprehension is, much less what it does.

Comment: @thegrinner added a pretty detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

You should use list comprehension here:

```
>>> content2[:] = [x if x!= 0.0 else None for x in content2]
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(content2)
[-0.112272999846,
 -0.0172778364044,
 None,
 0.0987861891257,
 0.143225416783,
 0.0616318333661,
 0.99985834,
 0.362754457762,
 0.103690909138,
 0.0767353098528,
 0.0605534405723,
 None,
 -0.105599793882,
 -0.0193182826135,
 0.040838960163]
```

Comment: Please include an explanation on what you're doing. I doubt anyone new to Python understands what a list comprehension is, much less what it does.

Comment: Any particular reason for the `[:]` after `content2`?

Comment: @tobias_k it mutates `content2` itself rather than assigning the name to a new list. If you have another variable like `y = content2` before the operation, it will be updated after this, instead of referring to the old list

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your code a bit gives the desired result:

```
for i in range(len(content2)):
    if content2[i]==0:
        content2[i] = None
```

In your code you subtract an integer from a list in the line:

```
for i in range((content2)-1):
```

but subtracting an integer from a list is not defined. len(content2) returns an integer that is equal to the number of elements in the list, which is what you wanted.